# Can't Compile basic Hello World Plugin

Tags: gazebo-plugin, ros-kinetic

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi I'm in the plug in tutorial (hello world) and when I try to compile I have the following error message.

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/random:35:0,
                 from /usr/include/ignition/math2/ignition/math/Rand.hh:20,
                 from /usr/include/ignition/math2/ignition/math.hh:18,
                 from /usr/include/sdformat-4.0/sdf/Param.hh:34,
                 from /usr/include/sdformat-4.0/sdf/Element.hh:24,
                 from /usr/include/sdformat-4.0/sdf/sdf.hh:5,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/common/Plugin.hh:42,
                 from /home/blackviper/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_tutorials/src/simple_world_plugin.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support \
```

And a lot more erros follow after that. Is this a sort of compatibility issue? I'm just starting out gazebo ros plugins. I'm using gazebo 7 btw.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20411/can%27t-compile-basic-hello-world-plugin/) by [BlackViper](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6212/blackviper/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes, this is a compatibility issue with c++ 11.

To fix that, just add the following line to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
```

Source: https://answers.ros.org/question/216842/ros-using-c-11-how-to-use-with-catkin/

---

Originally posted by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) with karma: 376 on 2018-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BlackViper](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6212/blackviper/) on 2018-09-13**:
Thank you!